# Background colour won't stay blue when saving figure produced using osmnx

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

I'm trying to save a figure's background as blue whilst mapping the road network of Berkeley, CA. The problem is that when saving the figure, the blue background does not persist, but changes back to default (white).

I can change the background color using `ox.plot_graph(bgcolor='b'`) but the state does not persist when I save to a PNG image.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how get the blue background color of the plot to persist when I save the image?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox

place = 'Berkeley, CA, USA'

G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type=network_type)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, fig_height=8, show=False, close=False, edge_color='w', bgcolor='b', edge_alpha=0.2, node_color='none')
plt.savefig('c:/Users/sgscombe/Documents/fcc/test.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color after plotting on the axis instance `ax`

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, fig_height=8, show=False, close=False, edge_color='w', bgcolor='b', edge_alpha=0.2, node_color='none')
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('b')
```

Comment: You put me in the right direction, you can do `fig.savefig('c:/Users/sgscombe/Documents/fcc/lol.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())` as by default I believe it sets it as white!